# Setting the locale via RCP-Designer

Tags: reporting, locale, birt

Is there an option in the reportfiles for BIRT to enforce a locale? I want my reports to have a german number formating no matter what.

Thanks in advance!:-)

Comment: I know that the locale can be set via IEngineTaskInterface, but want to avoid this. 

BIRT 2.1.3, RCP Designer

Answer (score 0):

The locale is going to be dictated by the engine rendering the report document form your design.  This allows for a design to be portable across and enterprise both departmentally and geographically.

Can you apply a numeric formatting mask to the elements in the report?  If you want to always use a certain format for numbers this is the way to go.  Click on the data element or label and choose the "Format Number" properties group.  From there you can tweak the numeric formatting through a standard set of options or apply a specific mask.  This will ensure consistent numeric regardless of who or what is generating a report document from your design.